# Google Cloud Storage Client not working on local dev_server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm running SDK version 1.8.8 and r127 of the GCS client...

I have a folder called /localGCS in my Home directory... my app is also in my Home directory. From my app's directory, I call dev_appserver.py with the following:

```
$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml loadandprocess.yaml downloader.yaml --storage_path=../localGCS
```

And my localGCS folder was populated by:

```
~/localGCS$ ls
datastore.db  search_indexes
[mybucketfolder]                  logs.db       xsrf
```

Where the file I'm trying to get is inside [mybucketfolder]. However, I'm still getting an error:

```
NotFoundError: Expect status [200] from Google Storage. But got status 404.
```

Any ideas? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

From your description

> .../localGCS in my Home directory... my app is also in my Home directory...

I see that your home directory and your app's directory are the same. I also see that `/localGCS` in inside home directory. If that is the case, you should use

`--storage_path=./localGCS/[mybucketfolder]`.

**--storage_path** is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command).